# How can I add headers to compress statics on a django server in response headers?

Tags: django, optimization, static, pagespeed

Now I am working on site `optimization`. I use the `pagespeed` service. Writes that need to `compress` static files. In the documentation of Django, I found the `middleware` who is responsible for this, added it.

Added file compression headers to `request headers`.

**Response headers**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 23183
Content-Type: application/javascript
Date: Mon, 09 Sep 2019 14:18:34 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 06 Sep 2019 09:09:22 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.8
```

**Request headers**

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: csrftoken=Lp7qIg3c8hrfWa1GhP2V104Zfem6hz5z63jbLDQHAxxUARRsEgCGZ9pApd4auNfV
Host: 22186d6d.ngrok.io
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: https://22186d6d.ngrok.io/
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36
```

But they need to be added to the `response headers`, so that pagespeed protects this item. How can I do that? The `Django's` server is used.

Link for check page from `pagespeed` - https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2F22186d6d.ngrok.io

Comment: The pagespeed report isn't working currently for your site because it's returning an error (500). But if the problem is to compress your static files, then this has little to do with Django, I hope: What web server are you using to serve your static files? Read [my blog post](https://www.dedi.co/blog/entries/2018/12/17/deploying-static-files-aws-django-part-1) to understand what you need to do to server static files in production.

Comment: I just wanted to test it all locally through the ngrok tunnel, and only then upload it to the production server where nginx is used

Comment: But Django shouldn’t be doing the compression at all. Use whitenoise to do that for you for the static files . And let nginx do the compression for the uploaded media files. And better yet, add a CDN so compression at runtime only needs to be done once per file.